# Show that $z=w$ iff $r_1=r_2$ and $\theta_1=\theta_2$.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Let $z = r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $w = r_2e^{i\theta_2}$. Prove that $z=w$ iff $r_1 = r_2$ and $\theta_1 = \theta_2$.

$$z = w \iff r_1e^{i\theta_1} w = r_2e^{i\theta_2} \iff$$
$$r_1(\cos \theta_1 + i \sin\theta_1) = r_2(\cos\theta_2 + i\sin\theta_2) \iff $$

Now, if $r_1 = r_2$ then it's easy to see that it must be that $\theta_1 = \theta_2 + 2\pi k$. How to show that if $r_1\ne r_2$ then $w\ne z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z=w \to |z|=|w|\to r_1=r_2$. Now, $z=w\to arg(z)=arg(w)\to \theta_1=\theta_2$.

Comment: I thought about it but it could be that $r_1 = -r_2$ yet $|z|=|w|$.

Comment: Oh actually $r$ must be positive. Thanks

Comment: Downvote: This argument is circular and completely begs the question of why $z = r_1 e^{i\theta_i}$ implies $r_1 = |z|, \theta_1 = \arg(z)$.